# Using ajax with JSON in a jquery calendar from ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm using a jquery calender that uses Ajax with JSON to populate its events
I want to return the JSON array from an ASP.net C# function
I would like to know if I'm doing this the wrong way as I can't manage to populate it 
the calendar name if you are interested is Zabuto 
https://github.com/zabuto/calendar

and here's my code

Javascript

```
<script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
                language: "en", today: true, show_days: true, nav_icon: {
                    prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>',
                    next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>'
                },
                ajax: {
                    url: "Default2.aspx/date",
                    modal: true,
                }
            });
        });
```

C#

```
public class Event
{
    public string date;
    public bool badge;
    public string title, body, footer, classname;
}
    [WebMethod()]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]

    public static string date()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Event event1 = new Event();
        event1.date = "2014-3-20";
        event1.badge = true;
        event1.title = "Event";
        event1.body = "body";
        event1.footer = "footer";
        event1.classname = "purple-event";
        return js.Serialize(event1);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return a JSON array with event objects. It looks like you are returning a single event.

```
[
  {"date":"2014-07-30","badge":false,"title":"...","body":"...","footer":"..."},
  {"date":"2014-07-31","badge":true,"title":"...","body":"...","footer":"..."}
]
```